# Trouble Passing Objects to Functions in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, winforms, pass-by-reference

New user here. I don't do any programming/coding by trade and have limited educational experience, so most of what I know is from tinkering around. I'm working on a PowerShell script that builds  a GUI and am having some trouble updating one GUI item based on editing another GUI item. I've simplified it to show the issue I'm having.

Here is the function that gets called:

```
function GUITitleTextBox_TextChanged
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
        [parameter(Mandatory=$True, Position=0)][System.Object]    $Sender,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$True, Position=1)][System.EventArgs] $EventArguments,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$True, Position=2)][String]           $Text,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$False, Position=3)][System.Object]   $ControlToUpdate
    )
    
    Write-Host $Sender.Text
    Write-Host $Text
    Write-Host $ControlToUpdate.Text
}
```

and here is the relevant code that creates the object and adds the event:

```
#Add the GUI Title textbox
$GUITitleTextBox       = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$GUITitleTextBox.Text  = "Default Form"
$GUITitleTextBox.Width = 240
$GUITitleTextBox.Add_TextChanged({GUITitleTextBox_TextChanged -Sender $this -EventArguments $_ -Text $this.Text -ControlToUpdate $GUITitleTextBox}) #Add an event when text changes.
$Form.Controls.Add($GUITitleTextBox) #Add the textbox to the Form
```

and here is the console output from this:

```
Default For
Default For

Default Fo
Default Fo

Default F
Default F
```

Anything passed to the function with $this works correctly as shown with the two Write-Host commands sending data, but when passing the object with the variable name ($GUITitleTextBox) it doesn't work. I can add a Write-Host $GUITitletextBox.Text directly below the code that creates the object. If when declaring and instantiating the $GUITitleTextBox I do $script:GUITitleTextBox to set the scope to the entire script I can then of course change the Text property.

To further complicate things, on a different script, I am able to pass a Windows Forms Object to a function just fine following the same format.

Function from other script:

```
function ContainerDimensionControlChanged()
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
        [parameter(Mandatory=$True, Position=0)] [System.Object] $CallingControl,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$True, Position=1)] [System.Object] $Container,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$True, Position=2)] [string]        $Axis,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$False, Position=3)][System.Object] $ControlToUpdate
    )

    <Removed because it's not relevant>

    $ControlToUpdate.Value = $Container.$Axis
}
```

and here's the code that calls it ($Panel and $WidthTextBox are both other form elements created earlier/later in the same function that runs this code):

```
$WidthSlider = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TrackBar
$WidthSlider.Top = 45
$WidthSlider.Left = 330
$WidthSlider.Name = "WidthSlider"
$WidthSlider.AutoSize = $true
$WidthSlider.Minimum = 5
$WidthSlider.Maximum = 750
$WidthSlider.Value = $PanelDefaultWidth
$WidthSlider.Add_ValueChanged({ContainerDimensionControlChanged $This $Panel "Width" $WidthTextBox})
```

So why does the second one work while the first one doesn't? What am I missing?